Repeated Dotted Image Background displaying in different sizes in different areas even with same CSS
I am building a Table of Contents page with a specific design.
As per design, each title should be followed by dots till the end of the line.
The size of the dots will also vary depending on the title's size.
I have used the heading  tag as wrap and inside there is an anchor  tag. I have used the pseudo "::after" element to display the dot. I have used a dot image with Background repeat CSS.
This works as expected. But I am facing a weird issue.
For example, the Dot design of H1 will be bigger. The dot design of H2 should be a bit smaller. The dot design of H3 should be even smaller. The page will have multiple H1s, H2s, and H3s.
The issue is dots inside H3s display differently. Dot inside One H3 is bigger and another one is smaller. Even though they have the same styles.


.outer{max-width:600px;overflow:hidden;}
h1, h1 a { font-weight: 400; font-size: 26px !important; border-left: 4px solid #000; color: #000; line-height: 38px; padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
h2, h2 a { color: #006da3; font-size: 23px !important; font-weight: 400; border-left: 4px solid #006da3; line-height: 30px; padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
h3, h3 a { color: #000; font-size: 21px !important; font-weight: 400; border-left: 4px solid #2690cd; line-height: 28px; padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
h4, h4 a { color: #000; font-size: 19px !important; font-weight: 400; border-left: 4px solid #71a3bc; line-height: 26px; padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
h5, h5 a { color: #000; font-size: 16px !important; font-weight: 400; border-left: 4px solid #000; line-height: 21px; padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
.heading1 a, .heading2 a, .heading3 a, .heading4 a, .heading5 a, .heading6 a { padding-left: 0px !important; border: 0px !important; margin-left: 0px !important;text-decoration:none; }
.heading_title { margin: 0; } 
.heading1,.heading1 a { font-size: 23px !important; line-height:34px; }
.heading2,.heading2 a { margin-left: 15px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height:28px; } 
.heading3,.heading3 a { margin-left: 30px; font-size: 17px !important;line-height:25px; } 
.heading4,.heading4 a { margin-left: 45px; font-size: 16px !important;line-height:24px; } 
.heading5,.heading5 a { margin-left: 60px; font-size: 14px !important;line-height:22px; } 
.heading6,.heading6 a { margin-left: 75px; font-size: 12px !important;line-height:20px; }
.heading_title { display: flex; align-items: baseline; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; position: relative; }
.heading_title a { display: inline-block; width: fit-content; margin-bottom: 0; min-width: fit-content; }
.heading_title::after {margin-left: 5px;background-image: url(https://www.cwdev.apptec360.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/grey-box-repeater.png);background-size: contain;background-position-x: right;height: 3.25px;content: " ";width: 100%;display: inline-block;min-width: -webkit-fill-available;background-repeat: repeat;}
h2.heading_title.heading2::after { background-image: url(https://www.cwdev.apptec360.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/blue-box-repeater.png); height:2.5px; }
.heading_title.heading3::after {height: 2px;}
.heading_title.heading4::after,.heading_title.heading5::after { height: 1.75px; }
h2.heading_title.heading2 { width: calc(100% - 15px); } 
h3.heading_title.heading3 { width: calc(100% - 30px); } 
h4.heading_title.heading4 { width: calc(100% - 45px); } 
h5.heading_title.heading5 { width: calc(100% - 60px); }
<div class="outer">
<h1 class="heading_title heading1"><a href="#131">General Overview</a></h1>
<h2 class="heading_title heading2"><a href="#163">Introduction to AppTec360</a></h2>
<h2 class="heading_title heading2"><a href="#165">Supported Device Operating Systems</a></h2>
<h2 class="heading_title heading2"><a href="#169">Explanation of the “Supervised-Mode” on Apple Devices</a></h2>
<h3 class="heading_title heading3"><a href="#177">Available in the Supervised-Mode</a></h3>
<h3 class="heading_title heading3"><a href="#184">Adding a device to the DEP</a></h3>
<h3 class="heading_title heading3"><a href="#186">Adding a testing DEP</a></h3>
<h2 class="heading_title heading2"><a href="#171">Explanation of Android Enterprise</a></h2>
</div>



In the above demo, the titles "Available in Supervised-Mode", "Adding a device to the DEP", and "Adding a testing DEP" are H3s and they all share the same CSS and their pseudo element (::after) have the same background image and CSS. But as you see, they are displayed in different sizes. DOTS inside "Adding a testing DEP" is way smaller compared to other 2 H3s.
Adding the JS Fiddle link below for the same if that's helpful.
https://jsfiddle.net/rajeevRF/3qu9e0yL/19/

Adding an screenshot image of how it looks.

Apart from that the first and last dot might get "cut", they look pretty identical in size to me - both in the snippet above and in your fiddle, in both Firefox, and a Chromium-based browser.

Hi @CBroe, I have edited the question and added the screenshot of how it looks.

Just to confirm that, unlike @CBroe, I see that the 3rd H3 dots are a lot smaller (Edge/Windows10).

There seems to be a pattern, if more h3s are added then two sets of dots are one size and thenext wo sets are smaller and then the next two the larger size etc.

Yes. Not able to understand the logic here. @AHaworth

Can you confirm that you are also having this problem specifically in Edge then? Inspecting this in the other browsers, I can see that the ::after elements extend "outside" of the h3, effectively all having the same with - which is of course important here, because you applied background-size: contain. I am guessing Edge probably does not extend the pseudo element outside of the h3, but only to the right edge? Then the after elements would have different widths, depending on the text lengths - and then of course the background image would scale differently as well.

Hi @CBroe, I am having this issue in CHROME.
I tried adding same content for 2 H3s but still both are displaying dots in different sizes

@CBroe same problem seen on Firefox/WIndows10.

Rather than using images, you could use repeating-linear-gradient to create the dots you're after instead? It should resize better.


.dot-text {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2rem;
  /*You'll probably want to do some calcs here to size this custom property with your font size */
  --dot-size: 4px; 
  --dot-spacing: 6px;
}

.dot-text:after {
  content: " ";
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, gray 0, gray var(--dot-size), transparent var(--dot-size), transparent calc(var(--dot-spacing) + var(--dot-size)));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom 0.45rem left 0.5rem;
  background-size: 100% var(--dot-size);
}
<div class='dot-text'>This is some text</div>



Edited to add:
To apply different sizes e.g. in your example, set custom properties in the parent element


.outer {
  color: #000;
}

.outer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.outer [class^="heading"] {
  margin-block: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-left-width: 4px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  display: flex;
}

.heading1 {
  --dot-size: 4px;
  font-size: 23px;
  line-height: 34px;
  border-left-color: #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.heading2 {
  --dot-size: 3px;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 28px;
  border-left-color: #006da3;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #006da3;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.heading3 {
  --dot-size: 2px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;  
  border-left-color: #2690cd;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.outer [class^="heading"]:after {
  content: "";
  --dot-spacing: calc(var(--dot-size) * 1.5);
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, gray 0, gray var(--dot-size), transparent var(--dot-size), transparent calc(var(--dot-spacing) + var(--dot-size)));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom 0.5rem left 0.5rem;
  background-size: 100% var(--dot-size);
}
<div class="outer">
  <h1 class="heading_title heading1"><a href="#131">General Overview</a></h1>
  <h2 class="heading_title heading2"><a href="#163">Introduction to AppTec360</a></h2>
  <h2 class="heading_title heading2"><a href="#165">Supported Device Operating Systems</a></h2>
  <h2 class="heading_title heading2"><a href="#169">Explanation of the “Supervised-Mode” on Apple Devices</a></h2>
  <h3 class="heading_title heading3"><a href="#177">Available in the Supervised-Mode</a></h3>
  <h3 class="heading_title heading3"><a href="#184">Adding a device to the DEP</a></h3>
  <h3 class="heading_title heading3"><a href="#186">Adding a testing DEP</a></h3>
  <h2 class="heading_title heading2"><a href="#171">Explanation of Android Enterprise</a></h2>
</div>




Thanks for the alternative.
Is this compatible with all browsers?
Also, Can you update your code to support the dots of multiple sizes like my example?

Nice. Now this code snippet show different-sized dots for me, while the OP's snippet shows same-sized dots. I'm on Chrome v125.0.6422.78. (HTML displayers lore be like:)

The problem is that the background size is set to contain. It has to change to a suitable value


.outer{max-width:600px;overflow:hidden;}
h1, h1 a { font-weight: 400; font-size: 26px !important; border-left: 4px solid #000; color: #000; line-height: 38px; padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
h2, h2 a { color: #006da3; font-size: 23px !important; font-weight: 400; border-left: 4px solid #006da3; line-height: 30px; padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
h3, h3 a { color: #000; font-size: 21px !important; font-weight: 400; border-left: 4px solid #2690cd; line-height: 28px; padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
h4, h4 a { color: #000; font-size: 19px !important; font-weight: 400; border-left: 4px solid #71a3bc; line-height: 26px; padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
h5, h5 a { color: #000; font-size: 16px !important; font-weight: 400; border-left: 4px solid #000; line-height: 21px; padding-left: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px; }
.heading1 a, .heading2 a, .heading3 a, .heading4 a, .heading5 a, .heading6 a { padding-left: 0px !important; border: 0px !important; margin-left: 0px !important;text-decoration:none; }
.heading_title { margin: 0; } 
.heading1,.heading1 a { font-size: 23px !important; line-height:34px; }
.heading2,.heading2 a { margin-left: 15px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height:28px; } 
.heading3,.heading3 a { margin-left: 30px; font-size: 17px !important;line-height:25px; } 
.heading4,.heading4 a { margin-left: 45px; font-size: 16px !important;line-height:24px; } 
.heading5,.heading5 a { margin-left: 60px; font-size: 14px !important;line-height:22px; } 
.heading6,.heading6 a { margin-left: 75px; font-size: 12px !important;line-height:20px; }
.heading_title { display: flex; align-items: baseline; box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; position: relative; }
.heading_title a { display: inline-block; width: fit-content; margin-bottom: 0; min-width: fit-content; }
.heading_title::after {margin-left: 5px;background-image: url(https://www.cwdev.apptec360.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/grey-box-repeater.png);background-size: 7px 1px;background-position-x: right;height: 3.25px;content: " ";width: 100%;display: inline-block;min-width: -webkit-fill-available;background-repeat: repeat;}
h2.heading_title.heading2::after { background-image: url(https://www.cwdev.apptec360.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/05/blue-box-repeater.png); height:2.5px; }
.heading_title.heading3::after {height: 2px;}
.heading_title.heading4::after,.heading_title.heading5::after { height: 1.75px; }
h2.heading_title.heading2 { width: calc(100% - 15px); } 
h3.heading_title.heading3 { width: calc(100% - 30px); } 
h4.heading_title.heading4 { width: calc(100% - 45px); } 
h5.heading_title.heading5 { width: calc(100% - 60px); }
<div class="outer">
<h1 class="heading_title heading1"><a href="#131">General Overview</a></h1>
<h2 class="heading_title heading2"><a href="#163">Introduction to AppTec360</a></h2>
<h2 class="heading_title heading2"><a href="#165">Supported Device Operating Systems</a></h2>
<h2 class="heading_title heading2"><a href="#169">Explanation of the “Supervised-Mode” on Apple Devices</a></h2>
<h3 class="heading_title heading3"><a href="#177">Available in the Supervised-Mode</a></h3>
<h3 class="heading_title heading3"><a href="#184">Adding a device to the DEP</a></h3>
<h3 class="heading_title heading3"><a href="#186">Adding a testing DEP</a></h3>
<h2 class="heading_title heading2"><a href="#171">Explanation of Android Enterprise</a></h2>
</div>





Your screenshot and result of the above attached code seems different. Can you update the above code so I can see and understand the mistake?

Also I tried changing the background size to suitable value but still the size differs between H3s. However you screenshot seems to be displaying correctly. Can you provide code to understand better?
